# Linear transformation-its essence and geometric approach.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

How does one understand graphically which map is linear and which one is not?I list 2 conditions below which I intuitively think to be both necessary and sufficient graphically for a map to be linear.I will restrict myself to transformations from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$,where $n,m = 1,2,3$.Then I think that the following checking will do:

1.Grid lines will remain parallel and equally spaced.

2.Origin remains fixed at origin.

3.Any line will remain a line or squish into a point.
I think checking these and only these conditions will guarantee that the map is linear.If I am wrong then give a counterexample and if correct,then give me a formal proof.

Comment: By grid lines I mean the lines that we see in graph paper parallel to basis vector i.e.usually the axes.Grid lines for any basis means similar kind of lines as mentioned but parallel to the present/current basis vectors.

Comment: For more precise defintiion see 3blue1brown essence of linear algebra

Comment: The map $x\mapsto 0$ does not satisfy your first condition.

Comment: Are you saying this because grid lines coincide.You may take this also as parellel grid lines with 0 space between each.

Comment: I think you need to be more precise about what you mean by grid lines. Are you just talking about the standard $x, y, z$ grids, or are you including other grids too? What are the grid lines in the $1$-dimensional setting?

Comment: You may see 3blue1brown essence of linear algebra videos,you will get what I mean to say.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar I have seen most of them, though quite a while ago. In fact, [I think I put you on to them](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3293703/interpreting-a-linear-map-geometrically#comment6774727_3293703). I distantly remember a video where grid lines remaining equally spaced was mentioned, but I don't remember which one, and I'm pretty sure it didn't contain the answers to my questions. This is more a question about how you've interpreted these conditions.

Comment: If the transformations “squish” certain lines, then you’re not going to have grid lines any more, either.

Comment: You can think of those grid lines reducing to grid points in that case,it is a limiting or degeneracy case,considering like this,you can say grid lines remain parallel.

Comment: You can also suggest how to make the statement that grid lines remain equally spaced ,more mathematical and precise.